# Is (a^p )(b^q) a regular language

Tags: nlp, regular-language

I read somewhere that {(a^p)(b^q):p,Q belong to N} is a regular language. However, i dont think this is correct. This can be proved using pumping lemma. Just want to verify if my solution is correct

Let y be ab . Thus, x(y^n)z does not belong to L as there will be some b's before a's for n>=1. However, expression does not allow this. Thus, (a^p)(b^q) is not a RL

Comment: This should probably go to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7):

It was a while ago I used the pumping lemma, but *a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>q</sup>* is definitely a regular language. It's even trivial to write a regular expression for it! *a** *b**

The similar looking *a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>p</sup>* is not regular though, because when starting to consume *b*-symbols, you need to remember how many *a* symbols you have consumed, and a finite automaton is not able to "remember" an arbitrary number. This is not a problem in your case!

Comment: isnt a^p b^q already a regular expression?

Comment: Yes, if you *fix* p and q, you can write *aaaaaaaabbbbb* which is a regular expression. But when he defines the language, he says it should include all choices of p and q.

Answer (score 0):

The pumping lemma says:
If a language A is regular => there is a number p (pumping length) where, if s is any string in L such that |s| >= p, then s may be divided into three pieces s=xyz, satisfying the following condition:

1. xy<sup>i</sup>z is in L for each i>=0
2. |y|>=0
3. p>=|xy|

The right way to show that a certain language L is not regular is to suppose L regular and try to reach a contradiction.

If you try to suppose that your language is not regular you should first search the kind of string that represents the irregularity of the language.
Lets try with a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>n</sup> for n>=0.

We can do some assumption on this string: since |xy|<=p we know that y is only made of a. At this point you can pump it as much times as you prefer but xy<sup>i</sup>z is a member of your language for every i>=0.

In a similar way you will not reach a contradiction if you choose a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>p</sup> for n>=0.

L={a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n>=0} is not regular, but you do not have constraints on p and q(I mean, it is not required to count both occurrences of a and b).

However a language is regular if and only if it can be expressed with a regular expression. And in this case you can do that: a*b*. So you can conclude that this language is regular.

Edit: 
for p<=q the language is not regular but you are considering any p and q.